# what is the function of Target:="f"5-ChampIndex?

Tags: autohotkey

```
Target:="f"5-ChampIndex
send {%Target% down} ;centers camera on teammate to follow
PixelSearch, ax, bx, 78, 87, 75, 87, 0x010d07, 10, Fast RGB ;checks for own HP specifically if below 65% HP
if ErrorLevel=0
```

I don't understand what {%Target% down} and {%Target% up} do, could someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume `ChampIndex` gets a value between 0 and 4, so the first line creates a variable that holds the a string like `f1`, `f2`, `f3`,..
Then `% %` is the legacy way of [retrieving](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#retrieving) a variable in a legacy statement.
So you end up with send commands like `send {f1 down}`, which means start holding <kbd>F1</kbd> down.